# Failed to enable MSI-X interrupt in Linux System

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, pci-e

I am working on PCIe based Cyclone V FPGA board in Linux Platform.

I have tried with legacy interrupt which works fine in my PCIe Driver. Now, I want to enable MSI-X interrupt in my PCIe driver.

MSI-X interrupt is implemented in FPGA system and I am getting total count 4 msix vectors in output of lspci command.

I have tried to call pci_enable_msix() routine to enable MSI-X interrupts which stuck my Linux System after loading driver with that routine.

I have also tried to call pci_enable_msi() routine which successfully enabled msi interrupt with free irq number allocated in pdev->irq.

Does anyone has idea or solution about this type of problem for MSI-X interrupt in Linux System?

Comment: Can you provide your probe code and the kernel dmesg error ?

Comment: I have changed code and now I am able to enable MSI-X Interrupt with free IRQ number provided by system, After that, I have registered that IRQ with one handle and triggered IRQ but not able to get Interrupt Event for that.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any idea for this as soon as possible.

Comment: Finally, I am able to generate MSI-X Interrupt successfully in Linux Host System by changing FPGA System Design.